# Active record join with group by name instead of object

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I am running this query

```
Device.joins(:reviews).group(:brand).average(:average_rating)
```

...and get this output

```
{#<Brand id: 1, name: "Phonak", created_at: "2013-08-26 22:25:07", updated_at: "2013-08-26 22:25:07">=>#<BigDecimal:6b4dc90,'0.788E2',18(45)>, #<Brand id: 2, name: "Oticon", created_at: "2013-08-29 21:03:06", updated_at: "2013-08-29 21:03:06">=>#<BigDecimal:6b4e320,'0.8070000712 076823E2',27(45)>, #<Brand id: 5, name: "Siemens", created_at: "2013-09-07 21:34:18", updated_at: "2013-09-07 21:34:18">=>#<BigDecimal:6b4eb68,'0.8111111111 111111E2',27(45)>, #<Brand id: 7, name: "Resound", created_at: "2013-09-13 16:10:34", updated_at: "2013-09-13 16:10:34">=>#<BigDecimal:6b4f090,'0.7342857142 857143E2',27(45)>}
```

However, I would like to have the results grouped by brand name not the actual Brand objects. Is this possible.

I tried:

```
Device.joins(:reviews).group('brand.name').average(:average_rating)
```

....but this is not working

Comment: Sorry, yes I have tried that as well

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'brands.name' in 'field list': SELECT AVG(`devices`.`average_rating`) AS average_average_rating, brands.name AS brands_name FROM `devices` INNER JOIN `reviews` ON `reviews`.`device_id` = `devices`.`id` GROUP BY brands.name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try with

```
Device.joins(:reviews).includes(:brand).group("brands.name").average(:average_rating)
```

Comment: The rails guides are pretty weak on joins